# Why are some tabs missing from one of our Administrator's home page?

Tags: civicrm-home, menu

We have three Administrators. I'm one. Another administrator has the "Contributions" and "Events" tabs missing from her CiviCRM home page. Mine aren't, and neither is the other Administrator's. Why is that? Don't all Administrators see the same set of tabs?

Answer (score 1):

Update based on feedback:

Go to Administer - Users and Permissions - Permissions, and then about half-way down there's a link to the CMS access control which assigns permissions based on their role in the CMS (drupal/wordpress/etc). If these admins have different "roles" assigned in the CMS then they might see different things because they might have different permissions.

So you either need to update their roles on their user record in the CMS, or update which permissions are assigned to various roles.

---

---

If by home page you mean the dashboard (url `/civicrm/dashboard?reset=1`) and by tabs you mean dashlets, then every user sees something different because they have control over which dashlets appear.

If that's not what you meant, can you clarify which page is the "home page" and what "tabs" means?

Comment: By home page, I'm referring to the dashboard I see labelled "CiviCRM Home". There are dashlets on that page that I see how to configure, but by "tabs" I'm referring to the pulldown menus on the top of that and every other CiviCRM page. On my pages, they are "Search", "Contacts", "Contributions", "Events", "Mailings", "Memberships", "Reports", "Administer", and "Support". Another Adminstrator only sees "Search", "Contacts", "Mailings", "Memberships", "Reports", "Administer", and "Support". They're missing "Contributions" and "Events". I don't see any way to enable/disable these pulldowns.

Comment: Ok thanks. Have updated answer.